# Trouble with Non-Boolean Types in HAVING/GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My instructions are to display INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr having the highest quantity.

I've been working with different variations of the following query:

```
SELECT INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr
FROM INV_LINE_ITEM
GROUP BY INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr
HAVING MAX(INV_LINE_ITEM.Quantity);
```

I keep receiving the error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'". I'm not really sure what this error means or how to fix my code.

I've also tried using:

```
SELECT 
STR(ILI.InvoiceNbr, 4) AS 'Invoice Number'
FROM INV_LINE_ITEM ILI
GROUP BY
ILI.FK_InvoiceNbr, ILI.Quantity
HAVING MAX(ILI.Quantity)
```

Comment: I'm trying to decipher your instructions. Are you meaning to return a single row, the one where the invoice has the highest value for Quantity? Or are you trying to display for each invoice the line item with the highest quantity (resulting in one row per invoice, rather than a single row)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be not the most efficient query. See whether the following query helps.

```
SELECT TOP 1    FK_InvoiceNbr
            ,   MAX(Quantity)   AS MaxQuantity
FROM            INV_LINE_ITEM
GROUP BY        FK_InvoiceNbr
ORDER BY        MaxQuantity DESC
```

You can also write it this way.

```
SELECT TOP 1    FK_InvoiceNbr
FROM            INV_LINE_ITEM
GROUP BY        FK_InvoiceNbr
ORDER BY        MAX(Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: That worked great. So, let me make sure I understand what's happening here. "TOP 1" is limiting the results to one row, then FK_InvoiceNbr and MAX(Quantity) are selected from INV_LINE_ITEM.

Was it not possible to use the HAVING clause like I had been trying to do in my original query?

Oh, and thank you for helping.

Comment: This is probably what the OP wanted.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I had ran into trouble by looking up the error I was getting instead of just looking up what a boolean expression was and how they were used with the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you trying to achieve by using MAX that way. You should know that MAX will bring the maximum value for that column in that group, thus, being the same type as the expression inside it.

A correct clause would be somthing like

```
Having max(field) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something to your MAX clause to make it something that evaluates to true or false.

For example:

```
HAVING MAX(ILI.Quantity) > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Having is kinda like conditions. The syntax would like like this

```
HAVING MAX(INV_LINE_ITEM.Quantity) > 3;
```

But that's not the condition you want.

I think what you want is this

```
SELECT INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr
FROM INV_LINE_ITEM
ORDER BY INV_LINE_ITEM.Quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will give you the INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr which has the highest Quantity.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING  is checking a condition about aggregated attributes about the groups which you are aggregating over.

Just like WHERE checks conditions on the rows, HAVING checks conditions on aggregates of the rows according to the grouping you specify in your GROUP BY.

Typically this is for showing the schools with more than 100 children or stores which sold more than $1000 worth of products.

You don't appear to be looking for that - you are looking for the group (actually not even the group, but the invoice) which has the largest quantity:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr, RANK() (OVER BY INV_LINE_ITEM.Quantity DESC) AS rnk
    FROM INV_LINE_ITEM
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rnk = 1
```

This will give multiples if they tie for RANK.  There are also a DENSE_RANK and a ROW_NUMBER analytic functions which [behave a little differently](http://www.oramoss.com/blog/2010/03/05/rank-v-dense_rank-v-row_number/).

If you wanted the line within each invoice with the highest quantity:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr, RANK() (OVER BY INV_LINE_ITEM.Quantity DESC PARTITION BY INV_LINE_ITEM.FK_InvoiceNbr) AS rnk
    FROM INV_LINE_ITEM
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rnk = 1
```